# play-ws several wsclients?

Tags: web-services, playframework, playframework-2.0

In my project, I have several classes to encapsulate third-party APIs. They look like

```
object foo {
  val wsClient: WSClient = ???

  ...
}
```

Should I share same WSClient, or it's better to have separate WSClient for each object?

Comment: I'm reusing the same one and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The default WS implementation is a singleton, so it's safe to share.